# A message body reader for FormDataMultiPart was not found

Tags: java, rest, multipart

I'm having some trouble with using FormDataMultiPart.

For some reason it looks as if the config for MultiPartFeature isn't getting called, even though i have put it in my web.xml, here is my code below.

 
 web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My rest method

```
@POST
@Path("/users/{userId}/images")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(@HeaderParam("securityToken") String securityToken, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId,
                            FormDataMultiPart form) {}
```

and the log message

```
09-Aug-2016 09:41:42.718 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity A message body reader for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=myRandomBoundary12345 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Comment: You are mixing Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x. Which version do you want to use?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jersey 2.x and a Servlet 3.x container, you don't need a `web.xml` deployment descriptor. For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html).

---

You could use the [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation to bind the named body part(s) of a `multipart/form-data` request entity body to a resource method parameter, as exemplified below:

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    ...
}
```

---

To use multipart features you need to add the [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies (see [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html)) on the classpath. And don't forget to register the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class.

For more details, check the Jersey [documentation about multipart requests](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart).

Comment: in my pom.xml i have jersey-bundle version 1.19

so i should use multipart 1.19.1?

Comment: @beerye Yes. I'm just wondering if you can upgrade to Jersey 2.x.

Comment: Yep, i may as well.. what do i need to change for version 2.x?

Comment: awesome thanks for your help, haven't got rid of my web.xml yet but might do that in the future

Answer (score 1):

I made this to work. In my case, I am using Jersey server 1.19 and jersey multipart 1.19 jars. Even then , it was throwing the same error.

After adding mimepull1.9.3 server, it got worked :-)